# Tab bar controller in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, landscape

All my app is in landscape mode .In some point I switch to a screen with Tab Bar Controller , but it's been placed like in portrait mode.I subclassed the UITabBarController and override the method "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" to return YES always but because the app is already in landscape , this method is not being called.
does anyway have an answer to this?
thanks
Giald

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to subclass UITabBarController. The tab bar will autorotate to landscape, if all it's subviews support landscape. Just make sure all tabs support landscape orientation and you should be fine afaik.

Answer (score 2):

Rengers is right, just make sure all tab views have YES in their respective shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation overrides. Depending on how you setup your app, check if any parent views have the shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation overrides. If so, it might be worthwhile commenting them out and leaving the overrides for the tab views only.

Comment: My app is configure for landscape only , and I just dragged the Tab Bar into the window in IB , and attached it to my outlet and that's it , and still the Tab Bar looks like in portrait mode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need an UITabBarController to take care of the tabbar orientation. Do you have one now, or are you just using a 'standalone' UITabBar?